# Hyper-V 12r2 across 2 physical networks

Tags: networking, virtualization, vlan, hyper-v-server-2012, virtual-network

Ok, so first off... I have done this multiple times with VMware and had zero problems so I assume I am missing something in Hyper-V.

Hardware I am working with:

- Single Dell R510 Host
- Onboard Dual Port Nic
- Quad Port Intel Nic
- 2x D-Link DES-1228 Switch

Immediate Goals:

- Dedicated Management (done)
- 1 Intel Port for LAN0 and 1 W7 Guest on network (done)
- 1 Intel Port for LAN1 and 1 W7 Guest on network (problem)

*** NOTES ***

- LAN0/Management same subnet
- LAN0 has DHCP server / LAN1 Strictly Static
- LAN0 and LAN1 are VLAN'd on D-Link as LAN0 - 01 - default, LAN1 - 02 - lan1
- Interface 0(LAN0) is on D-Link #1 and Interface 1(LAN1) is on D-Link #2

Now my issue...

When setting up the 3rd interface for LAN1 I have somehow un-intentionally created a  broadcast storm or something and stopped almost all LAN1 traffic. There is a small chance that it could have been spanning tree doing something weird (so says my CIO after disabling the interface and Guest) but I would not think that would cause such a huge problem.

Settings are fairly straight forward, but since I cannot leave the network in that condition I cannot troubleshoot. I do not like that I cannot modify Physical NIC settings within the HV Host. I noticed after I was forced to disable the Guest and Adapter using LAN1 that there was VLAN Identification for management operating system. Does this need to be enabled to isolate the VLAN traffic??

**Please excuse my ignorance of Hyper-V if I missed something simple**

As for the configuration, I removed what I had configured during the storm or possibly spanning tree craziness, so what I have now is different. What was configured yesterday that I "thought" was going to work looked a bit like this, but the 2 additional Virtual Networks (all configured the same, but wired a bit differently.

[image: HV V-Net Config]

3x Virtual Networks - All External
1 - Configured to on board Broadcom LAN0 Wired to LAN0 Dlink1
1 - Configured to Intel port 1 LAN0 Wired to LAN0 Dlink1 
1 - Configured to Intel port 2 LAN1 Wired to LAN1 Dlink2

As for the diagram a few people mentioned this is the quick down and dirty version. Nothing terribly complicated, and something I have done many times with VMware, but this client just refuses to let me implement vmware.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Please give [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault) a read.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without your NIC, vSwitch, and guest networking config. Also, a diagram of the portion of your network would be helpful. I think I understand what you're trying to do, and it's entirely possible on Hyper-V, so we'll need your config to tell you where you've gone wrong.

Comment: If LAN0, and LAN1, are both VLANs on your Dlink, why not just tag all your VLANs on all the ports, and put all interfaces on your hyper-v system into team, and then set the VLAN ID on the individual VM interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the input. There are actually separate switches involved, but the vlans are configured on both switches. I don't think the vlans have much to do with my issue considering the way I have them wired. I will post a diagram if I have time today, or tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, diagrams are immensely helpful for these kinds of questions - however, I think I understand what you are trying to do. It also is helpful if you explain what you want to do (your goals) along with what you did. If my answer is not relevant, please provide a diagram and information about your Hyper-V Virtual Switch/s and I'll adjust fire for affect.

> Setting up the 3rd interface for LAN1 I have somehow un-intentionally created a broadcast storm or something and stopped almost all LAN1 traffic

*If you have loop problems I feel sorry for you son, I got 99 problems but a switch ain't one.* You setup a Layer-2 loop on LAN1. Hyper-V Virtual Switches are just as susceptible to Layer-2 loops as regular switches. When you added the 3rd interface on your Intel Quad Port card to LAN1, you added a second path between your D-Link Switch and your Hyper-V Virtual Switch.

Depending on what your end goal is, you'll want to configure NIC teaming, a separate Hyper-V switch, VLANs or just passthrough of the interface to a guest.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had a feeling a diagram would help, but had issues posting it earlier. I'll try again if time permits.